# access controllers between pages in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Am new to angular js. My questions is, Is it possible to share one controller for different pages.

I  have a template of a site with me. Now am trying to code it with angular js.
I have 2 pages like home.html and new.html

home.html is like below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="kkCtrl">
        <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>

    <a herf="new.html" ng-click="getDatass('w')"> new</a>
    </div
    </body>
    </html>


 <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('kkCtrl',["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getDatass= function(a){
            $scope.k= a;
    }
    }])
    </script>
```

My new.html is

```
<div ng-controller="kkCtrl">
    <table>
    <tr><td>kkk</td>
    <td>lll</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    {{k}}
    </div>
```

My question is if i click 'new' link on home.html it should redirect to new.html and is it possible to view the value of '$scope.a' in new.html... Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that sharing controller between the pages is the best practice is AngularJS. Each view should have their own controller instead. If you want to pass the data between each view page, you can achieve it by using `angular-ui-router` to pass the parameters through `ui-sref`. I recommend you to read more about AngularJS Best Practice [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md). It provides a best styleguide used in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the scope variable set in home.html in new.html.

We can use same controller in any number of views. But when ever new view is created ,controller is created with new instance of $scope.

Controller behaves as if it's loaded for the first.

To solve you problem you can create an angular service or factory and use it for data sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Each view should have its own controller. If you want "global" functions / variables, i.e code shared among views (controllers) you should look at the [**services**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) concept. Create a service that holds the `k` variable, and make that service available in your controllers through dependency injection.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('myService', function() {

   //local variable or functions here
   var local = true;

   //variables and functions exposed to the outside 
   return {
      k: 0
   }
});
```

Now include `myService` as dependency for `kkCtrl` :

```
app.controller('kkCtrl',["$scope", "$http", "myService", function($scope, $http, myService) {
```

you can now set or get `k` :

```
$scope.getDatass= function(a){
  myService.k = a;
}
```